# Can't get my JButton to Display

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, jbutton

I am writing a maze program that runs a mouse around the maze GUI.  I'm not sure how to update an existing button in my GUI to a new color everytime the program loops.

I thought I could add a new button over the top of the existing ones. *Just ask me if you'd like the GUI code to look at.*

This is getting updated now that I tried adding the new button to the already existing content pane, but I suspect that adding a button on top of a button is messing up the GUI.  Reason being is that the button screen goes slanted when I run the code.

Here are three methods that I'm using.

This is what I was thinking I could do but it doesn't work.  I figured that I could just pass in the updated row and column to the `drawRat()` method.  The button shows up in GUI, but it's slanted and splits my existing button layout.

```
 public static String update(String toMaze){
        char [] newPos = toMaze.toCharArray();
        int x = 10;
        int y = 1;

        if (newPos [1] == 'r'){
             y--;
        }
        if (newPos [3] == 'r'){
             x--;
        }
        if (newPos [5] == 'r'){
             x++;
        }
        if (newPos [7] == 'r'){
             y++;
        }

        Maze.drawRat(x,y);
```

This is the `drawRat()` method.  I guess I should say that I moved my JFrame and content pane into the class constructor as `static` so that the whole program would have scope. so `c.add()` references that.

```
 public static void drawRat(int b, int r){

        JButton rat = new JButton();
        rat.setBackground(Color.GREEN);
        rat.setOpaque(true);
        rat.setBorderPainted(false);
        c.add(rat);
        rat.setVisible(true);
        rat.setLocation(b, r);
        rat.setSize(10,10);
```

Comment: Where do you add the JButton to a container?

Comment: Have you added the JButton to a parent component somewhere?

Comment: ha! nope, but i wonder i it worked the first time?

Comment: Setting the `size` and `location` will only work if you are using a `null` layout which is VERY unrecommended.  You may also need to (after you actually add the button) call `revalidate` and `repaint`

Comment: Why not add the button at start-up, but set it disabled until it is relevant?

Comment: it has to show throughout the program and either i have to move it each time the program loops or i have to update a button color thats already there everytime it loops so im going to update my code here because im having anohter issue with that

Comment: i just update the problem im having

Comment: This doesn't have to do with your particular question, but something that you should keep in mind.  `static` is not used for scoping unless you're making SHARED class variables.  Instead if it's something that's being instantiated it should be made a private variable (aka field) or class method. There is only one of something that is `static`, and that something is available to ALL class instances and shared between them.  If you have a static method, make sure you pass an instance reference to it if you need to reference a field value!

Comment: i thought thats what i was doing so that i could add to the content pane from different methods. anyway, i think the only way im going to be able to pull this off is to repaint a specific button corresponding to the updated (x,y) each time the program goes through a loop. the problem with that is that i have no idea how to use the (x,y) update from that method to repaint a button in a different method.